# Drop-Down-Menu to display all records from a query into a table AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, sql, ajax, drop-down-menu

How do I display all the records from a query that I executed into a table when I choose a `id` from my `car_types` drop-down-menu.

Here is the code I had done so far, I keep getting an error whenever I run my SQL query 
`$carResult = mysqli_query($link, $carQuery)`, how do I solve it or is my method of doing wrong?

Error: `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cars\carShop.php on line 54`

index.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_car');

if (!$link) {
    die(mysqli_error($link));
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Car Shop</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#type").change(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "getCars.php",
                        data: "type_id=" + $(this).find(":selected").val(),
                        cache: false,

                        success: function(msg){
                            query = $.parseJSON(msg);
                            $('#query').html(query);
                        }
                    });
                });
                $("#type").trigger('change');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="type" name="type">
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM car_types";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<option value ='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['type_name'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
        </select><br>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Car ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $carQuery = " <div id='query'></div>";
            echo $carQuery;
            $carResult = mysqli_query($link, $carQuery) or die(mysqli_error());
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($carResult)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?><td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['name'];?><td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['price'];?><td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

getCars.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_car');

if (!$link) {
    die(mysqli_error($link));
}

$typeId = $_GET['type_id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type_id = $typeId";


echo json_encode($query);
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by multiple outputs? please explain.

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: Change type into POST and `$typeId = $_GET['type_id'];` into `$typeId = $_POST['type_id'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute a query

```
$carQuery = " <div id='query'></div>";
echo $carQuery;
$carResult = mysqli_query($link, $carQuery) or die(mysqli_error());
```

While $carQuery is a div with a query in it, that's not gonna work. Try to execute this query within getCars.php and return the result.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_car');

if (!$link) {
   die(mysqli_error($link));
}

$typeId = $_GET['type_id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type_id = $typeId";

$carResult = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($carResult)) {

              echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
             }

        ?>
```

All you have to do now is assign the results to the right table via the success function of your AJAX call.

In your index.php

```
   <?php
   $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_car');

   if (!$link) {
         die(mysqli_error($link));
   }
   ?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Car Shop</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#type").change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "getCars.php",
                    data: "type_id=" + $(this).find(":selected").val(),
                    cache: false,

                    success: function(rslt){

                        $('#carResult').html(rslt);
                    }
                });
            });
            $("#type").trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="type" name="type">
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM car_types";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<option value ='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['type_name'] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
    </select><br>

    <table border="1">
        <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Car ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="carResult">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can use to allow me to execute the query?

Comment: What you could do is excecute the query in getCars.php and then echo the results via json_encode instead of echo-ing the query. In your AJAX call instead of assigning the query to the div, assign the results.

Comment: @DonutQuan I've updated my code with some example on how to do this.

Comment: You mean like this?
$result =  mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
echo json_encode($result);

$carResult = " <div id='query'></div>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($carResult)) {....
...
}

I am still getting the same error

Edit- Sorry did not see your example, shall try it now

Comment: @DonutQuan No not like that, look at my example.

Comment: How do I assign the results to the right table?
What do I put within the echo json_encode();

Comment: @DonutQuan I've updated my code, I'm not really sure if it's gonna work as I didn't test it, but it should be something like it.

Comment: Hmm it somewhat works but the table looks disorganised as the values are at different parts of the table. Is there no way in which I can just get the particular type_id and run a SQL query within my index?

Comment: @DonutQuan Could you post a screenshot of what the result is and the html of the page after you selected something? I don't think that that is possible atleast no unless you want to refresh the page, if you don't want to refresh you'll need AJAX and you'll be at the same problem as you are now.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/27y2614/8

It does display all the values but a bit jumbled up

Comment: @DonutQuan I see, could you provide me some source code? When you're on the page and selected something use rightmouse button <view page source> and then paste the table in your post?

Comment: @DonutQuan Nevermind I think that I know what's the problem. In your while loop replace the last `<td>` with `</td>` like this: `echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";` (I've also edited this in my post.)

Comment: I think there is a small typo. Instead of 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type_id = $typeId";  
should be $query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type_id = '$typeId'"; The commas is missing.

Comment: This is almost 3 years old, don't bother it